# PHP is printing an extra 1 in the webpage

Tags: php

Question says it all. I am learning `PHP` from the book "PHP for absolute beginners, 2nd Edition" and in the second chapter, i have to build a PortFolio site.

My code is split 5 ways. I have a main `index.php` file and two other folders which contains `navigation.php`, `projects.php`, `skills.php` and `page.php`.

Code for index.php:

```
<?php

    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    ini_set( "display_errors", 1 );

    $pageData = new stdClass();
    $pageData->title = "Thomas Blom Hansen: Portfolio site";
    $pageData->content = include_once "views/navigation.php";
    $pageData->css = "<link href='css/layout.css' rel='stylesheet' />";
    $navigationIsClicked = isset($_GET['page']);

    if ($navigationIsClicked ) {
        $fileToLoad = $_GET['page'];
        $pageData->content .=include_once "views/$fileToLoad.php";

    } else {
        $fileToLoad = "skills";
    }

    $pageData->content .=include_once "views/$fileToLoad.php";
    $page = include_once "templates/page.php";

    echo $page;
```

I use `XAMPP 5.6.3` which runs `PHP 5.6.3`.
Before I added the if, it was working fine. I tried all possibilities, but always, a 1 was printed just after the `<body>` tag ends. I am just a beginner.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

(I put a view comments to explain whats going on!)

File Structure:

```
|
| - index.php
| - navigation.php
|
| - templates
|       | - page.php
| 
| - views
      | - skills.php
      | - projects.php
```

index.php:

```
<?php
    //Error reporting only for testing environment
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>

<?php 

    //To save some code lines i put that in a function
    function getContent($path) {
        ob_start();
        require_once($path);
        $content = ob_get_contents();  
        ob_end_clean(); 

        return $content;
    }

    $pageData = new stdClass();
    $pageData->title = "Thomas Blom Hansen: Portfolio site";


    $pageData->content = getContent("navigation.php");  
    $pageData->css = "<link href='css/layout.css' rel='stylesheet' />";

    if( !empty($_GET['page'])) {
        $fileToLoad = $_GET['page'];

        $pageData->content .= getContent("views/$fileToLoad.php");

    } else {
        $fileToLoad = "skills";

        $pageData->content .= getContent("views/$fileToLoad.php");
    }

    $page = getContent("templates/page.php");

    $page = str_replace('%%$pageData->title%%', $pageData->title, $page);
    $page = str_replace('%%$pageData->css%%', $pageData->css, $page);
    $page = str_replace('%%$pageData->content%%', $pageData->content, $page);

    echo $page; 

?>
```

navigation.php:

```
<nav>
    <a href='index.php?page=skills'>My skills and background</a>
    <a href='index.php?page=projects'>Some projects</a>
</nav>
```

projects.php:

```
<h1>Projects I have worked on</h1>

<ul>
    <li>Ahem, this will soon be updated</li>
</ul>
```

templates/page.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>%%$pageData->title%%</title>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
        %%$pageData->css%%
    </head>

    <body>
        %%$pageData->content%%
    </body>
</html>
```

views/skills.php:

```
<h1>Skills and educational background</h1>

<p>Read all about my skills and my formal training</p>
<?php 
    echo "test";  //Little example to show that php gets parsed and that's also why the file extension still *.php is
?>
```

Output/ source code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Thomas Blom Hansen: Portfolio site</title>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
        <link href='css/layout.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    </head>

    <body>

<nav>
    <a href='index.php?page=skills'>My skills and background</a>
    <a href='index.php?page=projects'>Some projects</a>
</nav>




<h1>Skills and educational background</h1>

<p>Read all about my skills and my formal training</p>
test


    </body>
</html>
```

**Side Note:**

Here i used `require_once` so that if you have a complicated website files doesn't get multiple times included! (See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php)

Also added `%%` before and after a php variable in the template so that is less likely that you write a text with this name!

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I am having trouble to understand what the `$page = str_replace('%%$pageData->title%%', $pageData->title, $page);` is doing.

Comment: @PrithvishBaidya Your welcome! What do you don't understand?

Comment: I'm also having trouble with the getContent function. Could you please explain what `ob_start()` means?

Comment: I'm not understanding the str_replace fucrion. What does it do?

Comment: @PrithvishBaidya Okay :D So Str_replace, replaces as the name says 2 strings which each other! In this example it's search: `%%$pageData->title%%` in the variable `$page` and if it matches it gets replaced with: `$pageData->title`. ob_start starts the output buffering, so to say it's catching the output. And so you can include a file get the content and clean it all up! Also a short exmple: `ob_start();
        echo "test";
        $content = ob_get_contents();  
        ob_end_clean();` You will never see 'test' on you're page since it's in the output buffering! BUT `$content` = `test`

Comment: Still not understanding how the `$content = ob_get_contents();` works.

Comment: I searched the net as well as the manual and finally understood it. Thanks a lot and keep up the good work!

Answer (score 2):

```
include_once "templates/page.php";
```

Will return 1 if the file "templates/page.php"; is properly included. 
Hence will $page be equal to 1. So echoing $page will echo 1.

You should only use  `include_once "templates/page.php";` And not assign it to a variable that you then echos!

**This is how include works:**

By running `include_once "templates/page.php";` PHP will include the entire file in the current PHP document. and by doing this will also execute the code. If the include is successfull include_once will return TRUE witch when echoed is outputed as 1.

Comment: You're welcome! If my answer was of help to you you should mark it as correct by klicking the checkmark under tha answer rating!

Comment: @PhilipG Since OP doesn't seems to understand fully how include works you could make a short example like how the code looks like after the include is done! Also i think a answer only should be accepted if it's the solution to the answer and the most helpful one!

Comment: @Rizier123 Thanks for the feedback! I will update the answer with an example! But since this is the only answer and that it is solving OPs question i think it should be marked as correct either way!

Comment: I tried and reloaded an bang, nothing was displayed.

Comment: Then I tried `echo include_once "templates/page.php":`

Comment: But still, 1 was displayed.

Comment: every time you echo the return value of a successful include_once call this will echo a 1. You shouldn't echo the return of include_once.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do the following.

```
$page = include_once "templates/page.php";
echo $page; // comment out this line
```

Replace with:

```
include_once "templates/page.php";
```

and 1 will be removed. The include of the page returns True(1) or false but you don't need to `echo` it.

Comment: Not workin, already tried it.